# PDF albarán sacar el nº de pedido

Tags: prestashop

estoy intentando sacar en el pdf del albarán el número de orden (no la referencia del pedido).

Se que hay cambiarlo en delivery-slip.tpl pero no se como decirle ahí que me saque el campo "nº de orden o de pedido"

alguna ayuda por favor?

Tengo prestashop 1.6.1.20
Creo que el tema está en decir /classes/pdf/HTMLTemplateOrderSlip.php 
que te saque el coja el numero de pedido y luego lo enseñes en la plantilla delivery-slip.tpl

Aqui es donde me pierdo totalmente. ¿Alguien ha hecho algo similar?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Charly. Yo estuve trabajando tiempo atrás con PS el tema de los pedidos. Te recomiendo concretar un poco más la pregunta, dar más información de lo que estás haciendo, en qué parte (front-office o back-office) versión de PS, si estas trabajando sobre algún módulo y cuál es, qué código estas cambiando etc. porque si alguien no es super-experto en prestashop o está haciendo exactamente lo mismo que tu (y entiende lo que preguntas) no te va a poder ayudar.

Comment: Así por lo pronto, un TPL si recuerdo bien es un "template", la parte que genera la vista, no basta con modificarlo para mostrar un dato adicional. Si el dato que requieres mostrar no aparece por defecto es posible que no le llegue desde la base de datos, es decir que no se está solicitando en la/s queries que intervienen en primer lugar para obtener los datos de esos pedidos.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El tpl que debes cambiar es: `/pdf/delivery-slip.summary-tab.tpl`

Cambia el codigo: `{$order->getUniqReference()}`

Por este: `{$order->id}`

Comment: perfecto, eso era, muchas gracias